# How to convert mjpg file type to mpeg or flv?

Tags: video, conversion, encoding

I`ve already asked how to do it with ffmpeg but nobody replied. Maybe anybody know how to convert from mjpeg format? Do not suggest to use virtual dub to convert to avi as all it does is putting mjpeg inside avi container and I need to convert from mjpeg to some other format like mpeg or flv.

Comment: What is the second format? It's gotten garbled somehow

Comment: ref to the other question: http://superuser.com/questions/29893/how-to-convert-mjpg-file-type-to-flv-using-ffmpeg

Comment: yes, and there`s no answer, that`s why I reposted and without asking to convert with ffmpeg only.

Comment: Can you please post a link to a sample file? Its hard to figure out ffmpeg options w/o a file to work with.

Comment: link to file : http://www.onlinedisk.ru/file/205435/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem with that file is actually the audio sampling rate, 11024 Hz isn't supported by MP3. Easy enough to fix:

```
ffmpeg -i MVI_2130.avi -ar 11025 test.flv
```

Of course, there are a lot of quality options you may want to set, such as the video (`-vb`) and audio (`-ab`) bitrates.

The ffmpeg output actually told you this:

```
FFmpeg version SVN-r19468, Copyright (c) 2000-2009 Fabrice Bellard, et al.
⋮
Output #0, flv, to 'test.flv':
    Stream #0.0: Video: flv, yuv420p, 320x240, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 90k tbn, 15 tbc
    Stream #0.1: Audio: libmp3lame, 11024 Hz, 1 channels, s16, 64 kb/s
⋮
Error while opening encoder for output stream #0.1 - […]
```

Note how the error was with stream #0.1, which is the audio stream. It (unfortunately!) doesn't tell you that the sample rate is wrong; you just have to know what your output codec is capable of. And for mp3, that's [8000, 11025, 12000, 22050, 24000, 32000, 44100, and 48000 Hz according to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MP3#Bit_rate).

Comment: Thanks, it really does video conversion now. But sound conversion failed and the result file is silent. Can it be fixed in some way?

Comment: Sound conversion worked just fine here... Did ffmpeg give any errors?

Comment: Just copied from stream mapping:
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0.0 -> #0.0
  Stream #0.1 -> #0.1
Press [q] to stop encoding
Warning, using s16 intermediate sample format for resampling
[libmp3lame @ 0x3df830]lame: output buffer too small (buffer index: 8359, free b
ytes: 1433)
Audio encoding failed

Comment: Weird, what version of ffmpeg are you using?